# How to find the expected value of infinite discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Question: A fair six-sided die is rolled repeatedly. Let $X$ be the number of times it is rolled until two different numbers are seen (so, for example, if the first two rolls were each $4$ and the third roll was $5$ then $X=3$).

How to I find the expected value? I realize that this is a geometric distrition and this is the expression I have for $\mathsf{E}[X]$:

$\mathsf{E}[X]=2\left(\frac 56\right) + 3\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right) + 4\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^2 + 5\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^3 + ...$

I wrote down an expression in terms of summation and this seems to be a airthmetico-geometric series but there has got be an easier way to compute the expected value. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that$$\mathbb{E}(X)=1+1\cdot\frac56+\mathbb{E}(X)\cdot\frac16$$follows from the problem statement.

Comment: @PeterForeman I can't see how it follows...can you please explain it?

Comment: The expected number of times rolled is given by $1$ roll for the initial number plus either $1$ roll with a $5/6$ chance provided we roll a different number or, with a $1/6$ chance, we roll the same number and the number of times rolled is increased by the expected amount.

Comment: An alternative is $\mathbb{E}(X-1)=1+\mathbb{E}(X-1)\cdot\frac16$, giving the same result

Comment: @PeterForeman wow that's smart...kind of like writing a recursive definition...thank you so much it makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are faster ways, but one relatively simple approach is

$\mathsf{E}[X]=2\left(\frac 56\right) + 3\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right) + 4\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^2 + 5\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^3 + \cdots$

so $\frac16 \mathsf{E}[X]=2\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right) + 3\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^2 + 4\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^3 + 5\left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^4 + \cdots$

and subtracting $\frac56 \mathsf{E}[X]=2\left(\frac 56\right) + \left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right) + \left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^2 + \left(\frac 56\right)\left(\frac 16\right)^3 + \cdots$

i.e. $\mathsf{E}[X]=2 + \left(\frac 16\right) + \left(\frac 16\right)^2 + \left(\frac 16\right)^3 + \cdots$

This is essentially $1$ more than a geometric series but you can in fact do the same thing again

so $\frac16 \mathsf{E}[X]=2\left(\frac 16\right) + \left(\frac 16\right)^2 + \left(\frac 16\right)^3 + \left(\frac 16\right)^4 + \cdots$

and subtracting $\frac56 \mathsf{E}[X]=2 -\frac 16 = \frac{11}{6}$

and thus  $\mathsf{E}[X] = \frac{11}{5}=2.2$